# Is it possible for arrays to contain methods, classes etc.?

Tags: java, arrays

I know that it is possible to store integers, strings etc. into arrays. But I wonder, if it is also possible to store "bigger" things like methods, classes etc. into arrays and also access them as easily as their Integer, String counterparts.

I can imagine several occasions, when something like that would be useful. Does someone have an example Code, in which such an array of methods is used?

I would like to see the notation in particular, when you also want the methods to be used on given integers or strings. Maybe then it looks like this `a[i](m, n, "qwerty")`, dunno. a[i] is a method; m,n are integers, "qwerty" is a String; 
this notation would make it really easy to write a for-loop and use several methods one after another without having to write them all down again. 
As it seems arrays won't allow to do that, are there any other options? I will check the use of "reference of methods"

Comment: This question is quite vague - can you elaborate on what you're trying to achieve (even in pseudocode)?

Comment: @Imago I don't understand. How can a data structure contain a class? You mean object (instances of the class) ? If that is the case arrays already can contain objects.. String is a class. If you want utilities method the class Arrays has some very nice one..

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html

Comment: Do some reasearch about serialization/deserialization - that covers everything except methods. For methods the closest thing that comes to mind is "remoting".

Comment: How hard it's becoming to find answers in StackOverflow lately,"why do you want to do that" is becoming a trending... Of course you can, I will share some piece of code in a few minutes if nobody else has done it yet

Comment: You may have noticed that @Code-Apprentice posted an answer saying you can't store methods in an array and someone else said he was wrong. The problem has to do with you asking "if it is also possible to _store_ "bigger" things like methods, ...  into arrays ...". I'm with Code-Apprentice on this, you can't _store_ methods in an array. It has now become clear that you are just asking if you can have _references_ to methods in an array, and that's a different thing.

Comment: @TauroMx That's because there have been a lot of XY problems posted.

Answer (score 1):

In Java, methods are not first-class citizens and cannot be treated as data. This means you **cannot** store methods in an array.

On the other hand, you **can** store objects in an array:

```
MyClass[] myArray = new MyClass[10];
```

This creates an array of 10 `MyClass` objects.

Comment: Java reflection offers Method objects, so it would technically be possible to store "methods" in an array. Although it would likely not fulfill the poster's request for "access them as easily as"

Comment: @cello This isn't nearly the same as storing the method itself in an array. I imagine that the OP has some exposure to languages like Lisp or Haskell where you **can** store a function in a list.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice I was thinking of `C` arrays of pointers to functions ... But even in that case, the functions pointed to would have to have the same definition.

Answer (score 1):

You can define an array holding objects of any class.

```
MyClass myObjects = new MyClass[2];
```

Then you can assign an instance of your class to a position in the array :

```
myObjects[0] = new MyClass();
```

And call any of MyClass's methods on it :

```
myObjects[0].doSomething(someParameter);
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes.  In Java, a class you defined will contain methods, or even variables from other classes, and you can define arrays of your class.  Example:

```
class Myclass {
    Myclass(){...}
    String data;
    void process(){
        var1.doSomething();
    }
    OtherClass var1, var2;
}
```

So if you define array variable in this class, here is example:

```
Myclass[] myClasses = new Myclass[5];
myClasses[0]=new Myclass();
...
myClasses[1].process();
```

My answer may look vague, but if you update your question with real examples, then it will make more sense.

Comment: `myClasses[1].process()` will cause a NPE.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice did you notice ...?  Those are necessar codes to initialize all objects in that array

Comment: There...now the eliding is much more obvious.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want to create an array of objects and access the methods of those objects. The array + position is a reference of the object stored inside the array at that position so you simply need call the method.

Example.

```
   public class Demo {

      public static void main(String[] args)
      {
          Demo[] array = new Demo[5]; // array of 5 Demo objects of class Demo.

          for (int a = 0; a < array.length; a++) // looping through the array to instantiate each object.
          {
               array[a] = new Demo(); //instantiating the object at position 'a'.
          }

          for (int a = 0; a < array.length; a++) // looping through the array to access each object.
          {
              array[a].sysOut(a); //accessing the sysOut method of the Demo object at position 'a' and passing int 'a' as a parameter.
          }
      }   

      public void sysOut(int a) // method of class Demo accepting an int parameter.
      {
          System.out.println(a + " is a Demo object.");
      }
  }
```

So a class can not be held inside of an array, but an object made from that class can be. Once you have your object inside of the array in a specified position, the array name and position is the object's reference.

Answer (score 0):

You have some examples there in the answers of how to refer classes, this is to show you how to refer methods. This is just an example of the syntax, you must implement a better approach to inspect only desired methods and to collect them better. You can even inspect signatures dynamically instead of statically parameterizing method calls as in this example.

You may want to use this kind of code only when you are creating a framework and not final solutions. In final soultions you're supposed to know exactly what you are calling and be ready with the inputs and outputs you're expecting.

```
package com.something;

import java.lang.reflect.Method;

public class Test {

public void someMethod() {
    System.out.println("This does nothing");
}

public String anotherMethod(String param) {
    return "This does something with your param: " + param;
}

public static class InnerTest {

    public double thirdMethod() {
        return Math.random();
    }

}

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    Class[] clazzArr = new Class[2];

    clazzArr[0] = Test.class;
    clazzArr[1] = Test.InnerTest.class;

    for ( Class auxClass : clazzArr ) {
        for ( Method auxMethod : auxClass.getMethods() ) {
            // inspect these to know what you must send to current parameter to be able to invoke it
            Object[] parameterTypes = auxMethod.getParameterTypes();
            // inspect this to know what type of object do you expect
            Object returnType = auxMethod.getReturnType();

            // for simplicity, I know which parameters to send in my example
            switch( auxMethod.getName() ) {
            case "someMethod":
                // I know it doesn't receive any parameters
                auxMethod.invoke(auxClass.newInstance(), new Object[0]);
                break;
            case "anotherMethod":
                // I know it does receive an string parameter and I know it doesn't print anything,
                // so I have to print it here
                System.out.println( auxMethod.invoke(auxClass.newInstance(), "My Name is Imago") );
                break;
            case "thirdMethod":
                // in the other method I just return a double with no parameters
                System.out.println( "Random number: " + auxMethod.invoke(auxClass.newInstance(), new Object[0]) );
            default:
                // even public static void main and other Object methods will be included, you must have another algorithm to include only desired ones
                break;
            }
        }
    }

}
```

}

You might be interested in reading next:

[Java Reflection](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/)

[Java Reflection: Method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Method.html)